# ThreadPoolTaskExecutor shutdown/re-run issue

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, java.util.concurrent

I'm trying to implement multi-thread continual task execution using Spring's 'ThreadPoolTaskExecutor'.

**Here is my class to work with it:**

```
@Component
public class AsyncWorker implements Worker  {
    public int threadCount = 5;
    private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();

    @Async
    public void doWork(Runnable runnable){
        executor.initialize();
        executor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        executor.setCorePoolSize(threadCount);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(threadCount);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(0);
        executor.setThreadGroupName("A");

        for (int i=0;i<5;i++) {
            executor.submit(runnable);
        }
        System.out.println("Active threads: " +executor.getActiveCount());
    }

    @Async
    public void StopTasks(){
        executor.shutdown(); 
    }
```

Usage:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("api/test")
public class SendController {

    ThreadPoolExecutor executor =  new ErrorReportingThreadPoolExecutor(5);

    @Autowired AsyncWorker worker;
    boolean IsRunning = true;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/start_new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Callable<String> StartNewTask(@RequestBody LaunchSend sendobj) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

//      System.out.println(sendobj.getThreadsCount());
        Runnable runnable = () -> {
            while(IsRunning) {
                MyVoid();
           }
        };

        worker.doWork(runnable);

        return () -> "Callable result";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/stop", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Callable<String> StopTasks()  {
        IsRunning =false;
        if(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName() != null &&  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName() != "anonymousUser") {
            worker.StopTasks();
            return () -> "Callable result good";
        }
        else { return () -> "Callable result bad";}
    }
}
```

**The main problem is:**

When i send a start request 1st time - everything is ok (unless i don't see changes in group's name(executor.setThreadGroupName("A"))).

But, after i sent stop requesting, and sending the start request again - executor doesn't launch the tasks. this is how it looks like:

```
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor-4 Global iteration # 4
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor-2 Global iteration # 5
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor-5 Global iteration # 3
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor-3 Global iteration # 2
Active threads: 5
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor-1 Global iteration # 1
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor-2 Global iteration # 9
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor-3 Global iteration # 9
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor-5 Global iteration # 9
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor-4 Global iteration # 9
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor-1 Global iteration # 10
Active threads: 1
```

just showing "Active threads: 1". What can be a problem?

Btw, in future, i want to set custom name for ThreadGroup created by it (param transferred from POST request/Spring Security Context) and then be able to terminate all thread with some group name(group name will be the Spring Security username of the user who is launched threads.) Is it possible?

Comment: just FYI, mark boolean isRunnable as volatile and don't compare strings with != operator, use equals() method

Answer (score 0):

Once the tasks have completed their work they no longer exist, you would need to resubmit them to the scheduler in order to have them run again.  They do not stay within the executor indefinitely.

Comment: each time i'm sending a request to "/start_new" Controller, worker.doWork(runnable);
is called, which is re-submiting them, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

It may be a timing issue. Try to add a short wait like

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

just before

```
System.out.println("Active threads: " +executor.getActiveCount());
```

And try to write out also the pool size (to make sure if the pool size is set correctly):

```
System.out.println("Active threads: " +executor.getPoolSize());
```

Comment: there are iterator in MyVoid, it'll show the iteration # if it's a timing issue

Comment: Are these the outputs between active threads: 5 and active threads: 1 ? Then it's quite strange because the ThreadPoolTaskExecutor numbers are different, which also means currently exists really 5 threads and not 1.

Comment: OK I understand this already, but I'm asking which lines of the log output you provided printed after you call the method 2nd time? Right after the line "Active threads: 5" ?

Comment: thats wasn't a 1nd call yet. just MyVoid is simply having only this output, so it appears very fast. 2nd run is then 'active threads: 1' appears